# My reputation dropped and I don't know why

Tags: discussion, reputation

Yesterday I had a reputation of 20.  I was able to enjoy the chat rooms and take part in another level of participation.  After I posted my last question, and found the answer, then added a comment that I had found the solution, my reputation dropped to 19.

I do not understand how and why this happened.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have a look at your profile page which shows down-voted questions that caused your rep to drop - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2065840/detox

Comment: You need to check your user profile page.  It shows all statistics or links to pages that have that information.

Answer (score 7):

It's because your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24788426/436282 got downvoted.

See the help center docs on reputation here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Now you got to 9 when your post was on wrong forum (It was on main, this is meta).

Comment: Fortunately for him, it went back up when it was migrated since rep isn't affected on meta.

Comment: @AndrewArnold And now it's dropping again due to meta effect on the question that lost him points in the first place.

Comment: OK this is now officially a nightmare.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @Detox Post good content that gets upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788426/data-error-on-join-statement-in-query was downvoted three times.  Each downvote removes two reputation so you ended up losing six reputation for that question.