# Confused By Reputation Drop

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-users

I reviewed reputation-drop MSO questions & answers (e.g. particularly [this comprehensive answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269654/1810429), [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269805/losing-reputation-after-suggested-edit-which-are-not-mine/269807#269807), and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265978/my-reputation-dropped-and-i-dont-know-why))...but have not found an explanation for the drop I experienced this evening.

A few hours ago, my SO reputation was 4,078.  My MSO reputation remains 4,078, but my SO reputation dropped to 4,058 sometime over the last few hours; and I would like to understand why.

I do not see any downvotes in [my reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810429/j0e3gan?tab=reputation) to explain the drop, nor unaccepts or unupvotes.  The drop does not appear to be due to a deleted question(s) because my profile still shows 206 answers like it did earlier.

Might the drop be due to a user(s) who upvoted my answers in the past deleting their account?  I am familiar with the reputation audit page...but unclear how I would even be able to (dis)confirm user deletion's possible role.  Beyond that remaining possibility, I am unclear what else could underlie the drop...and would like to learn from it.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the "show deleted posts" box?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: `<HeadBang>`Oh, holy moly.`</HeadBang>`.  That was easy.  Thanks for teaching me about something I never noticed.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy:  And now my profile does, in fact, show 205 answers where it showed 206 previously.  I checked my answer count before posting as I indicated in my question: either I skipped a groove or it just caught up.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Now I see too from [a related MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) that I can mouse over the "removed" event in my reputation tab with "show removed posts" checked and see the cause of the removal.  In this case it is "post was removed" rather than "user was removed".  Thanks again for helping me learn quite a bit from this!

Comment: Do note that [that comprehensive answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269654/1810429) is a collaborative FAQ. The checkbox that you missed is a commonly overlooked item, so it might be worth calling out more clearly. Someone with a different perspective and/or less experience with the UI might be able to do a better job than I did.

Comment: @CodyGray:  Thanks.  That makes sense regarding the comprehensive answer I noted because it is verrry comprehensive; and after being pointed to the "show removed posts" check box, I could not help but wonder why it is not above the list of reputation activity rather than below it - FWIW.